# Is there a way to access other js history states than current

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history, popstate

Lets assume I did following:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var currentState = event.state; // returns {foo:bar}
    var previousState = ... ; // how to access {foo:baz}
};

history.pushState({foo:'bar'});
history.pushState({foo:'baz'});
history.back();
```

1. Is there a way to access previous state (the one you are leaving) in onpopstate callback
2. Is there a way to access the list of states, eg. `[null, {foo:bar}, {foo:baz}]`

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but I'd be willing to be the answer is no. Seems like it would be a privacy concern.

Comment: As long as your JS is doing most of the history manipulation however, there's nothing saying you can't store it on your own.

Comment: I dont really see how it could be a privacy issue, since all the states are handled withing the same page.

Just to be clear, I am not asking about accessing history outside current page, just states that I created on the current page.

Comment: Right, I'm just not sure the browser necessarily knows the difference. But since that's all you need to know then you can write a wrapper function around `pushState` that appends the current state to an array of previous states before pushing the next state. Create your own history.